# Stop raycasts from going through walls

Tags: c#, artificial-intelligence, raycasting

So Im making a game in which you have to be able to hide from the enemy. The enemy sees me and follows me when he sees me but when I put a wall between us, the raycast ignores the wall and makes the enemy still follow me. Im not using layers because I dont really understand what they do. Also I dont even know if I should use them. Here is my enemy ai script, in c#:

```
using UnityEngine; 
using System.Collections;

public class EnemyAI : MonoBehaviour { 

private GameObject playerTarget;
private SphereCollider col;
public Transform target;
public int moveSpeed;
public int rotationSpeed;
public int maxDistance;
private Transform myTransform;
public int RayDist;
public Vector3 position;

public float RayDir;


void Start ()
{
    playerTarget = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player");
    col = GetComponent<SphereCollider>();
    myTransform = transform;
    GameObject go = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
    character = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    target = go.transform;  

    var diagonal = transform.TransformDirection(1, 0, 1); 
    position = transform.position-transform.right*3;
}

CharacterController character;

void Update(){

}


void OnTriggerStay (Collider other)
{

    if(other.gameObject == playerTarget)

    {   

        RaycastHit hit;

        Vector3 dir = target.position - myTransform.position; dir.y = 0; 



        Vector3 fwd = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward * RayDist);

        if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, fwd, out hit,10))
        {
            if (hit.transform.gameObject == playerTarget)
            {
            Debug.Log ("Raycast entered ");
            myTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(myTransform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(dir), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime); 
            if (dir.magnitude > maxDistance) 
            { 
                character.Move(myTransform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime); 
            } 
            }
        }
        Debug.DrawRay (transform.position, fwd, Color.green);

        Vector3 slightright = transform.TransformDirection(new Vector3(RayDir,0,2) * RayDist);
        if(Physics.Raycast (transform.position, slightright, out hit, 10)){
            if (hit.transform.gameObject == playerTarget)
            {
            Debug.Log ("slightright Raycast entered");
            myTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(myTransform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(dir), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime); 
            if (dir.magnitude > maxDistance) 
            { 
                Debug.Log ("Left Raycast move function entered");
                character.Move(myTransform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime); 
            } 
        }
        }
        Debug.DrawRay (transform.position, slightright, Color.magenta);

        Vector3 right = transform.TransformDirection(new Vector3(RayDir,0,1) * RayDist);

        if(Physics.Raycast (transform.position, right, out hit, 10)){
            if (hit.transform.gameObject == playerTarget)
            {
            Debug.Log ("Right Raycast entered");
            myTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(myTransform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(dir), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime); 
            if (dir.magnitude > maxDistance) 
            { 
                character.Move(myTransform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime); 
            } 
        }
        }
        Debug.DrawRay (transform.position, right, Color.blue);

        Vector3 left = transform.TransformDirection(new Vector3(-RayDir,0,1) * RayDist);
        if(Physics.Raycast (transform.position, left, out hit, 10)){
            if (hit.transform.gameObject == playerTarget)
            {
            Debug.Log ("Left Raycast entered");
            myTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(myTransform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(dir), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime); 
            if (dir.magnitude > maxDistance) 
            { 
                Debug.Log ("Left Raycast move function entered");
                character.Move(myTransform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime); 
            } 
        }
        }
        Debug.DrawRay (transform.position, left, Color.red);

        Vector3 slightleft = transform.TransformDirection(new Vector3(-RayDir,0,2) * RayDist);
        if(Physics.Raycast (transform.position, slightleft, out hit, 10)){
            if (hit.transform.gameObject == playerTarget)
            {
            Debug.Log ("Left Raycast entered");
            myTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(myTransform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(dir), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime); 
            if (dir.magnitude > maxDistance) 
            { 
                Debug.Log ("Left Raycast move function entered");
                character.Move(myTransform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime); 
            } 
        }
        }
        Debug.DrawRay (transform.position, slightleft, Color.cyan);
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not checking if the object that is hit by the ray cast is actually the player. So your code basically says: "If this raycast hits ANYTHING, follow the player." To check which object is hit by the raycast, simply create a RaycastHit object and add that as a parameter to the Physics.Raycast calls. So your first RayCast would look like this:

```
RaycastHit hit;
if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, fwd, out hit ,10))
{
    if (hit.transform.gameObject == playerTarget)
    {
        Debug.Log ("Raycast entered ");
        myTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(myTransform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(dir), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime); 
        if (dir.magnitude > maxDistance) 
        { 
            character.Move(myTransform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but now it gives the error: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
EnemyAI.OnTriggerStay (UnityEngine.Collider other) (at Assets/EnemyAI.cs:56)

Comment: Did you add the 'out' in front of 'hit' in the raycast call? It is very important that you add that.

Comment: Ah thank you, I guess Im not that awake yet! It doesnt give any errors anymore. I still miss a piece here I think?

Comment: Is it still not working? Make sure your wall has a collider for the raycast to hit

Comment: I do have a cube with a box collider set up in my scene, but the rays still pass through and the enemy still focusses on the player.

Comment: And you changed all your Raycasts to also use a RaycastHit object now? Just making sure it isn't something simple right now.

Comment: I called RaycastHit hit one time; in the first line of the if(other.gameObject == playerTarget).

Comment: It is ok to create a single RaycastHit object in this case, but you have to use it for all the Raycasts to make sure the Raycasts only react if they hit the player.

Comment: If i do that, it nags about that it is already defines, so i guess the placement isnt right?

Comment: Could you maybe update your answer with the new code, then I can take a look at it?

Comment: I changed some things within unity and now it works, I dont get why but thanks!

Comment: Good that it works now, I honestly couldn't tell what was going on anymore. Glad it works now!